# Different height of nodes in a cluster dendrogram d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, cluster-computing, dendrogram

i have a question about d3.js
I have this basic example running: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nMD1.png
and a basic json format:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
     "name": "parent A",
     "children": [
       {"name": "child A1"},
       {"name": "child A2"},
       {"name": "child A3"}
     ]
    },{
     "name": "parent B",
     "children": [
       {"name": "child B1"},
       {"name": "child B2"}
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My javascript code is here:

```
<!doctype html></html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
.node circle {     
  fill: #fff;    
  stroke: steelblue;    
  stroke-width: 1.5px; 
} 
.node {    
  font: 20px sans-serif; 
} 
.link {    
  fill: none;    
  stroke: #ccc;    
  stroke-width: 1.5px; 
}
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var width = 600; 
var height = 500; 
var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()    
   .size([height, width-200]); 
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()    
   .projection (function(d) { return [d.y, d.x];}); 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")    
   .attr("width",width)    
   .attr("height",height)    
   .append("g")    
   .attr("transform","translate(100,0)"); 
d3.json("dendrogram03.json", function(error, root){    
   var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);    
   var links = cluster.links(nodes);    
   var link = svg.selectAll(".link")       
      .data(links)       
      .enter().append("path")       
      .attr("class","link")       
      .attr("d", diagonal);     
   var node = svg.selectAll(".node")       
      .data(nodes)       
      .enter().append("g")       
      .attr("class","node")       
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });    
   node.append("circle")       
      .attr("r", 4.5);    
   node.append("text")       
      .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })       
      .attr("dy", 3)       
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })      
      .text( function(d){ return d.name;}); 
}); 
</script>
```

But the problem is that i looked for d3 documentation but is not so good, so i want to put every node in a different height of the tree like this way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49a6v.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you could descend the tree with a recursive function and modify the y attribute on each child, incriminating the amount of modification each time you loop through the set of child nodes.

You will need some modifying function after the creation of the nodes but before the creation of the links:

```
  var nodes = cluster.nodes(root).reverse();
  create_offset(nodes[0]);
  var links = cluster.links(nodes);
```

the function for creating the offset could look something like this:

```
  function create_offset(node){
    if(node.children){
      //modify the y values of each child. increasing the offset each time
      var offset = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i<node.children.length;i++){
        node.children[i].y = node.children[i].depth * 100 + offset;
        offset += 20; //change this to change the degree of offset
      }

      //check each child to see if it has it's own children. If so, decend the tree recursively
      for(var i = 0; i<node.children.length;i++){
        if(node.children[i].children){
          create_offset(node.children[i]);
        }
      }    
    }
  }
```

Note: be sure `nodes[0]` in `create_offset(nodes[0]);` is the root node. I'm fairly sure it will be but you should double check

Comment: I delete the message because it wasnt correct. The problem is that this recursive function gives the same value and some nodes are in the same height. With reverse form it doesnt work

Comment: The solution is put the offset var out of the function and dont use the reverse() , the answer is good. Thanks